# Solving PDE using Lagrange method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The problem in this question is found in section 1.3.2 "*Determining the parametric structure of models*" by D.J. Cole et al.

I have a linear, 6-dimensional PDE:
$$
-\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}\frac{\phi_3}{p_4} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p_4} = 0
$$
where 
$$
f \mathrm{\quad is\ shorthand\ for\quad} f(\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3, p_2, p_3, p_4)
$$
But the remaining variables simply have zero-valued coefficients. I need to find the solution to be 
$$ 
\quad f(\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3, p_2, p_3, p_4) = F(\phi_1,\phi_2, p_2, p_3, \phi_3 p_4)
$$

So far I have tried this approach
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_4} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}\frac{\phi_3}{p_4}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\partial p_4} = \frac{1}{\partial \phi_3}\frac{\phi_3}{p_4}
$$
$$
\frac{p_4}{\partial p_4} = \frac{\phi_3}{\partial \phi_3}
$$

$$
\int\frac{1}{p_4} \partial p_4= \int\frac{1}{\phi_3}\partial \phi_3
$$

$$
\mathrm{ln}|p_4|= \mathrm{ln}|\phi_3| + C_1
$$

And to try the characteristic method
$$
\frac{\partial\phi_3}{-\phi_3 / p_4} = \partial p_4 = \frac{\partial f}{0}
$$
$$
-\int \frac{1}{\phi_3} \partial \phi_3 = \int 1\ \partial p_4
$$
$$
-\mathrm{ln}|\phi_3| = p_4 + C_2
$$

Though neither of these approaches seems to lead in the right direction and I do not have sufficient information to know where to be going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
-\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}\frac{\phi_3}{p_4} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p_4} = 0 \tag 1$$

Explanation of the first part :

Consider the total derivative of a function $f(\phi_3\:,\:p_4)$ :
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}d\phi_3+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_4}dp_4$$

And from Eq.$(1)$ : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_4} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}\frac{\phi_3}{p_4}$

$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}d\phi_3+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}\frac{\phi_3}{p_4} dp_4=0$$

$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_3}\left(d\phi_3+ \frac{\phi_3}{p_4} dp_4\right)=0$$

$$d\phi_3+ \frac{\phi_3}{p_4} dp_4=0$$

$$\frac{d\phi_3}{\phi_3}+ \frac{dp_4}{p_4} =0$$

$$\ln|\phi_3|+\ln|p_4|=\text{constant}$$

Also, there is a small mistake in the second part :

[image]

So, both methods leads to the same result, which can be written equivalently :
$$p_4\phi_3=C$$

The general solution of the PDE is :
$$f(p_4\:,\:\phi_3)=F(p_4\phi_3)$$
that is any function of the product $p_4\phi_3$.

The arbitrary function $F$ has to be determined according to some boundary condition (not specified in the above wording of the question).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am confused between the sign discrepancy in the two solutions, in the first the logarithms have opposite signs whereas in the second they have the same, meaning that the first resolves to $ \phi_3 / p_4 $ whereas the second finds the solution I am after of $ \phi_3 p_4 $. Is this just another mistake on my part?

Comment: Oh ! I didn't notice that. This is not only a sign mistake. In fact $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_4}$ is not a fraction. It is an indissociable symbol for partial derivative. One cannot separate $\partial f$ and $\partial p_4$. See the new edition of my answer in order to explain the correct writing.